Couldn't get a list of tags. Unexpectadly did not find the new dependency in the package graph. Package could not be resolved Xcode 16.1
I want to add packages like SnapKit, Resolver, etc. Actually, it doesn't matter what package I want to add - the same result. Even adding a local package. Here is an error error: Couldn't get a list of tags. Unexpectadly did not find the new dependency in the package graph: sourceControl(identity: snapkit, location: SwiftPM.SPMPackageDependency.SourceControlLocation.remote(SwiftPM.SPMSourceControlURL(sourceControlURL: https://github.com/SnapKit/SnapKit.git)), requirement: 5.7.1 – Next Major)


Steps that didn't help:

Clear Xcode’s Derived Data and Package Caches Manually:


Quit Xcode,
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData,
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/org.swift.swiftpm,
xcodebuild -resolvePackageDependencies -disablePackageRepositoryCache,
git config --global tag.forcesignannotated false,
swift package update


Delete and Re-add the Dependencies
Disable Package Caching Temporarily
Verify GitHub Access and Authentication
Check Network and GitHub Status (using git clone  - it works!)
Restart laptop
List item

Xcode 16.1
macOS 15.1 (Intel Core i7)
iOS 18.0

Same for me on Mac M1 Pro for another package

Same for Braze SDK

Actually same for adding any new package

UPDATE: You can fix the issue by updating to SourceTree version 4.2.10. No further actions needed
It's an issue related to SourceTree. In version 4.2.9, they added a setting to the .gitconfig file that's breaking SPM.
More info here: https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREE-8176
Citing @clopex:

Basically you need to run command in terminal: open ~/.gitconfig then
remove: [safe] bareRepository = explicit save it and that is


Yes, I confirm that it resolved this issue for me.

You saved my days!!!

I have this issue also. How to find these from Jira ticket? I deleted SourceTree app from mac completely or this is related to something else? I could not figure out

I found how to do it, sorry. Basically you need to run command in terminal:
open ~/.gitconfig
then remove:
[safe]
bareRepository = explicit
save it and that is

Updating Sourcetree to 4.2.10 solves the issue.

Indeed, updating SourceTree from 4.2.9 to 4.2.10 solved this. I had absolutely no clue this could have anything to do with SourceTree, a seemingly unrelated application.
